# Compare List/set elements

Tags: c++, list, set

I'm looking to compare two sets and display the missing elements in second set by iterating over the first set.

I've done using lists but it seems like an overhead iterating over the unordered list to find the elements.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
using std::list;

bool isExist(list <int> &original, int i)
{
 list <int>::iterator iter;

 for (iter = original.begin(); iter != original.end(); iter++)
 {
  if (*iter == i) {
   original.splice(original.end(), original, iter);
   return true; }
 }
 return false;
}

void FindMissing(list <int> &original, list <int> &missing)
{
 int count_exist = 0;

 list <int>::iterator iter;

 for (iter = missing.begin(); iter != missing.end(); iter++)
 {if (isExist(original, *iter))
  count_exist++;}

 int count_missing = original.size() - count_exist;

 iter = original.begin();

 while(count_missing > 0)
 {
  std::cout << *iter++ << std::endl;
  count_missing--;
 }
}

int main()
{
 list <int> list_data_1;
 list <int> list_data_2;

 //Fill the list.
 for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
 list_data_1.push_back(i);

 //Fill second list with missing elements.
 list_data_2.push_back(3);
 list_data_2.push_back(1);
 list_data_2.push_back(4);

 FindMissing(list_data_1, list_data_2);
}
```

How would you do the same with set?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have two sets:

```
std::set<int> s1;
std::set<int> s2;
```

and you want to get the set of elements that are in one but not the other, you can use `std::set_difference`:

```
std::set<int> difference;
std::set_difference(s1.begin(), s1.end(),
                    s2.begin(), s2.end(),
                    std::inserter(difference, difference.begin()));
```

`difference` will contain all of the elements that are in `s1` but not in `s2`.

`std::set_difference` works for any two sorted ranges, so you could use it with other containers as well (e.g., if your `std::list`s were sorted, you could use `std::set_difference` on them to find the difference).

Comment: Dang, beat me to it. Nice explanation.